# Other commands don't work. (Python, Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@bot.event 
async def on_message(ctx) :
    file = openpyxl.load_workbook("level.xlsx")
    sheet = file.active
    exp = [100, 200, 400, 700, 1100, 1600, 2200, 2900, 3700, 4600, 5600]
    i = 1
    while True :
        if sheet["A" + str(i)].value == str(ctx.author.id) :
            sheet["B" + str(i)].value = sheet["B" + str(i)].value + 2
            if sheet["B" + str(i)].value >= exp[sheet["C" + str(i)].value - 1] :
                sheet["C" + str(i)].value = sheet["C" + str(i)].value + 1
                await ctx.channel.send("Level UP !!\nLevel : " + str(sheet["C" + str(i)].value) + "\nExp : " + str(sheet["B" + str(i)].value))
            file.save("level.xlsx")
            break
        if sheet["A" + str(i)].value == None :
            sheet["A" + str(i)].value = str(ctx.author.id)
            sheet["B" + str(i)].value = 0
            sheet["C" + str(i)].value = 1
            file.save("level.xlsx")
            break
        i += 1
```

This code works well, but it prevents other commands from working.

I put this code at the end. But other commands still don't work.

How can I fix the error?

Comment: Add `bot.process_commands(message)` at the end of your `on_message` event. Also, you should have a `message` argument in your function definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working).

Use `await bot.process_commands(message)` at the end of the code, to run the event function along with the other commands.

Comment: Do I have to write this code at the end? Or should I write it at the end of the whole code before bot.run()?

Comment: at the end of the `on_message` event.

Comment: This is a correct line of code, but I believe it should go right before the line ```file = openpyxl.load_workbook("level.xlsx") ```